# Ext JS4: What configuration wraps text inside its parent's container?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a vbox panel on the right side of my page:

```
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'east',
            itemId: 'clipboard',
            autoScroll: true,
            width: 200,
            layout: {type:'vbox',align: 'stretch',pack: 'start'},
            collapsible: false,
            split: true,
            border: false,
        }
```

When an event occurs, I need to add a new image with text beneath it to the 'clipboard' strip:

```
var clipboard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[itemId=clipboard]')[0];
clipboard.add(
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'center',pack: 'start'},
        data: data,
        margin: '5 0 5 0',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'resources/images/clipboardItem.png',
            height: 32,
            width: 32
        }, {
            xtype: 'box',
            html: 'This text needs to wrap around because it is too wide to fit in the clipboard strip.'
        }]
    });
```

The image is correctly centered over the text.  The text should wrap around, so that it's not wider than the clipboard.  However, its container is not shrinking to the width of the strip.  The text length is determining the width of its immediate container.

What configuration changes do I need to make so that each item I add to the clipboard has a centered image, followed by a block of text that potentially wraps around within the bounds of the clipboard, and everything adjusts when the user changes the width of the clipboard?

http://jsfiddle.net/nxSmS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a width to the box...

```
xtype: 'box',
width: '100%',
html: '<p>This text is super long and will be too wide for the panel</p>',
```